# compare database entry with form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

this is my first question here so please do not roast on me.

I am currently working on a html, php, mysql project in school and I want to know if it is possible to compare the entry of a form in html with a table in my database to get its id.

The form looks like
Prename:""
Last name:" "

The table:
ID: '1'
Prename:'abc'
Last name: 'xyz'

Now, if someone fills out the form and submit, I want to send it to a function which looks through the database and if a match is found, returns the ID.

Thanks for your ideas!

Edit: As you want here is what I got so far includes the code from @Patchesoft
Still it isnt working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="db_class.php" method="post">
    <p>Vorname: <input type="text" name="prename"/></p>
    <p>Nachname: <input type="text" name="last_name"/></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start"/>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

And for the PHP part our teacher got us a class with a lot of functions to add and select from databases etc. The most important:

```
<?php 


DB::init(...); // The connection is ok. I just delted the login data for purpose

$prename = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['prename']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `ID` FROM `user` WHERE `prename` = '" . $prename . "' AND `last_name` = '" . $lastname . "' ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['ID'];
}


echo $result;

class DB {

    public static $db = null;
    public static $insertID;

    public static function init($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName) {
        self::$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
        if (self::$db->connect_errno) {
            $_SESSION['errors'][] = "MySQL connection failed: ". self::$db->connect_error;
        }
        self::$db->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
    }

    public static function select($table, $columns = '*', $key=null, $where = null, $limit = null, $debug = false) {
        $sql = "SELECT " . self::generateColumnList($columns) . " FROM $table";
        if ($where != null) {
            $sql .= " WHERE ".$where;
        }
        if ($limit != null) {
            $sql .= " LIMIT ".$limit;
        }
        if ($debug == true) {
            $_SESSION['debug'][] = __FUNCTION__ . ': $sql is <strong>' . $sql . '</strong>';
        }

        $result = self::$db->query($sql);
        if (self::$db->errno) {
            $_SESSION['errors'][] = '<p>select failed: ' . self::$db->error . '<br> statement was: <strong>' . $sql . '</strong></p>';
            return array();
        } else {
            $ret = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if (!empty($key)){
                    $ret[$row['id']] = $row;
                }
                else
                    $ret[] = $row;
            }
            if (count($ret) == 1) {
                return $ret[0];
            } else {
                return $ret;
            }
        }
    } 
    public static function select2($sql, $debug = false) {
        $result = self::$db->query($sql);
        if (self::$db->errno) {
            $_SESSION['errors'][] = '<p>select failed: ' . self::$db->error . '<br> statement was: <strong>' . $sql . '</strong></p>';
            return array();
        } else {
            $ret = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if (!empty($key)){
                    $ret[$row['id']] = $row;
                }
                else
                    $ret[] = $row;
            }
            if (count($ret) == 1) {
                return $ret[0];
            } else {
                return $ret;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are hundreds of tutorials around the net. Just use the big search engine and come back with code to show us what you have tried.

Comment: why would you think we would roast you? We are the nicest people in the world.

Comment: What code have you tried? can you "edit" your originial question and provide that code?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. It is not clear where you are having problems.  There are a number of concepts you need to understand to do what you want to do - HTML forms, relational databases/SQL, PHP extensions to work with MySQL, how to sanitize input data, asynchronous browser requests (if you are trying to use jQuery for this as might be inferred from your tag), etc.  Can you narrow down where specifically you are having problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to get your form input fields into variables and then make an SQL query that checks the data in your database. It's quite simple, but for a beginner there are some other things to consider.

1) Sanitizing your input. This is important to protect against SQL Injection attacks. The simple answer is to run it through mysql_real_escape_string() function to clean the variable, but there are much more better methods than this. Look up prepared statements.

2) Connecting to your database. Before you can do any querying to your database, you need to connect to it. It's quite simple to do, but you will need to look up how to do this.

As for some base code, try:

```
$prename = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['prename']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);

// Now check to see if the values match in your database
// This assumes you have already written your connecting to database code
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `ID` FROM `table_name` WHERE `prename` = '" . $prename . "' AND `lastname` = '" . $lastname . "' ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['ID'];   
}
```

This is a very basic script- it's what I as a beginning learned doing. There are much better ways of doing it, using PDO database drivers. But if you're just learning to do something in PHP and MySQL, this should get you going.

Comment: Automatic -1 for referencing long-deprecated `mysql_*` functions in your answer.

Comment: @MikeBrant Oops! Fixed.

Comment: Ok. I think I messed up some guide-lines in this community. I give this a try. Our teacher provided us a php class which inits the connection to our Database. So the connection is there but our teacher isnt the best at teaching us basic things in php, html, mysql...